# python thread pool copy parameters

Tags: python, multithreading, copy, pool

I'm learning about multithreading and I try to implement a few things to understand it.
After reading several (and very technical topics) I cannot find a solution or way to understand my issue.

Basically, I have the following structure:

```
class MyObject():
    def __init__():
        self.lastupdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    def DoThings():
        ...

def MyThreadFunction(OneOfMyObject):
    OneOfMyObject.DoThings()
    OneOfMyObject.lastupdate = datetime.datetime.now()

def main():
    MyObject1 = MyObject()
    MyObject2 = MyObject()
    MyObjects = [MyObject1, MyObject2]

    pool = Pool(2)

    while True:
        pool.map(MyThreadFunction, MyObjects)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think the function .map make a copy of my objects because it does not update the time. Is it right ? if yes, how could I input a Global version of my objects. If not, would you have any idea why the time is fixed in my objects ?

When I check the new time with print(MyObject.lastupdate), the time is right, but not in the next loop

Thank you very much for any of your ideas

Comment: Threading pickles objects. pool.map returns the objects. I usually do something like this: with Pool(2) as pool: object_list = pool.map(function, object_list). Just make sure the function returns the objects when it's done.

Comment: Basically yes, changes aren't "inplace". You need to edit an object and then return it in the function, and grab those returned objects from pool.map, which will return a list of whatever the function returns.

Comment: When the objects are passed to and from threads, they get pickled (serialized). So your original reference won't reference the changes in the threads. This is why you must return them again.

Comment: Thank you very much Neil, that was really fast ! I did not understand threading pool.map returned the objects. I'm gonna try this way. NB: as MyThreadFunction(OneOfMyObject) takes only 1 input object, It would return only 1 output object as well ?

Comment: Let me post an answer with an example. Yes, it will return one object.

Comment: Anyway, I think you lead me in the right way, thank you very much for your time Neil. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, python threading will serialize (actually, pickle) your objects and then reconstruct them in the thread. However, it also sends them back. To recover them, see the commented additions to the code below:

```
class MyObject():
    def __init__():
        self.lastupdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    def DoThings():
        ...

def MyThreadFunction(OneOfMyObject):
    OneOfMyObject.DoThings()
    OneOfMyObject.lastupdate = datetime.datetime.now()

    # NOW, RETURN THE OBJECT
    return oneOfMyObject

def main():
    MyObject1 = MyObject()
    MyObject2 = MyObject()
    MyObjects = [MyObject1, MyObject2]

    with Pool(2) as pool: # <- this is just a neater way of doing it than a while loop for various reasons. Checkout context managers if interested.

        # Now we recover a list of the updated objects:
        processed_object_list = pool.map(MyThreadFunction, MyObjects)

    # Now inspect
    for my_object in processed_object_list:
            print(my_object.lastupdate)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: (I put the infinite loop for the objects to update asap)  But if I do object_list = pool.map(function, object_list), does that mean that the function Pool will return the objects only when all the threads are done, doesn't it? so it won't go in the next loop beforehand (as that was the objective)?

Comment: Yes, the function Pool will return the objects only when all the threads are done, so it won't go in the next loop beforehand. I need to rethink the code then. Thanks again for your time Neil !

Comment: `pool.map()` will block until all the objects in the list have been processed by the number of processes the `Pool` contains (2 in this case) and the results collected in the the list returned. The `while True:` isn't needed to things to update asap—if just an infinite loop which means the `main()` function which prevents it from ever returning.

Comment: Yes this won't yield results. I'm not sure what the neatest solution is for a threaded generator, but you could hack something together by splitting your list into batches (of size 2), threading the processing of those batches, and then yielding the results before the next batch is processed. Then you would get 2 out at a time.

Comment: Also consider whether "do_something()" is io bound or CPU bound. If it's CPU bound then threads won't speed it up because of the python GIL. if your replace "from multiprocessing import Pool" with "from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool", then you'll get access to a process pool, which spins up multiple python interpreters. This is much faster for CPU bound operations.

Comment: What do you mean by batches (of size 2) ? Basically, I want all MyObject to DoThings in the same time, indefinitely and in parallel (as they would respond with different time lapse)

Comment: It's mostly io bound (Internet requests)

Comment: You are creating two threads. This means that at any given time only two objects are being operated on. What I'm suggesting is that you create a list of lists of size 2 from your original list, process 2 at a time in 2 threads, yielding the results as they finish. That way you won't have to wait until they are all finished before you can start using the results. You will get 2 at a time out.

Comment: Also just to be certain, threading in python isn't strictly parallel. The only thing threads can do in parallel is wait for io. But only one thread can execute CPU operations at a time because of the python GIL (I'm guessing from your camal case that you aren't from a python background, this is a python snag if you aren't careful).

Comment: If "do_something()" is itself an infinite loop, then you can't recover the objects in the main function like this. You will need to look into message queues and stuff in the threading library.

Comment: "you aren't from a python background" no I'm not but I love it :)

Comment: do_something() send a request to a website. But as the website would take a random time to respond, I would like to process the data as soon as they arrive, and send another request to the same website as soon as I got the data

Comment: So, yes the idea would be to create 2 threads with infinite loop. message queues and stuff in the threading library: i'm on it. have a nice eve Neil !

Comment: Pleasure to contribute Joseph. Can I ask, if you believe that my posted answer answered your original question, please accept it. If you still have any additional, follow up questions, then I recommend opening up a new question.